# When getting models yii gets me no data received

Tags: yii

I keep getting this error and I have no idea where to go.
I reinstalled my database and apache2, thinking it maybe related to the database.
If there's a line that says `new Model();` the web page always give me `No data received`.

Once I remove that line, there's no message and the page loads (of course I can't load the forms or anything related to the model). So this must be a model or database issue, but I have no idea what or why this is happening?
Any direction would be great.

Comment: can u share your codes with us?

Comment: Having only `new Model();` by itself do not populate the variable with data from the database, so it is normal not to have data. If you share your code maybe we can help you more.

Comment: The problem is there is no code. It is just purely the default yii. I'm suspecting it's an issue on install then?